# Fused location provider does not always return the location according to the criteria

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I have this code for request location updates:

```
private var fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
                    priority =
                        when (locationProviderType ?: SettingsProvider.getProviderType(context)) {
                            LocationChangeProviderType.HIGH_ACCURACY -> LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                            LocationChangeProviderType.BALANCED -> LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
                        }
                    interval = timeIntervalInMillis
                    maxWaitTime = timeIntervalInMillis
                    smallestDisplacement = minDistanceInMeters
                }
                fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                    locationRequest,
                    locationCallback,
                    Looper.getMainLooper()
                )
```

`timeIntervalInMillis= 1000`, `minDistanceInMeters = 10f`.
But provider doesn't return updates with this criteria. For example, I can walk and see updates only two times for 100 meters, even if I walk very slowly. This happening even with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY.
How to fix it?

Comment: Try walking/ running 10 meters or more in 1 sec and see the result.

Comment: Do you want to say, that I should run 10 meters in 1 sec? According to documentation, it works not like that. These params means that that there is should be 10 meters from last point and more than 1 second.

Comment: Share the documentation.